# Action Bar No Resource Found.

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I was trying to run the following code from the android studio guide:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
```

However, for the following code:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
android:title="@string/action_search"
```

It says:

```
Cannot resolve symbol '@string/action_search' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Validates resource references inside Android XML files
```

And that no resource matches the given name.

I am not sure how to make of it. I have googled extensively and these are possible solutions?

1. Download the image set at "https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#action-bar-icon-pack". I was unable to find what to download, and where to extract to.

I have tried:

1. Setting the minSdk to 11 (and 22) in gradle and in manifest
2. Redoing the project and reading very closely.

If someone could shed some light on this situation I would be very grateful! I have tried doing my own research/ googling/ experimenting but it has come to no avail.

Comment: Is your string resource added in strings.xml? As from the error it seems the string is the missing resource not the drawable...

Comment: Seems like there is no "action_search" string inside your string.xml. Look inside your values folder and create a value for your reference like `<string name="action_search">Search</string>` in your string.xml

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsár the problem is the same for both of them. I just took one of the errors to highlight the point. I'm not sure if the string resource is added in strings.xml. This is the following code there:<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
</resources>

Comment: @MarkusRubey Thanks so much! Now I only need to fix drawable. One down one to go. I think I may be able to solve it the same way. Should I make an xml file in drawable and add something like that in it? It has the same issue

Comment: I made a new drawable xml and added the following code:     <drawable name="ic_action_search">Search</drawable>
It still doesn't seem to work though. This is the error : Error:Error: In DataSet 'main', no data file for changedFile 'C:\Users\Andy\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\main_activity_actions.xml'. This is an internal error in the incremental builds code; to work around it, try doing a full clean build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the string value for your action_search reference.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="action_search">Search</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
</resources>
```

To fix your empty reference for your drawables you have to drop an image with the name of your reference like ic_action_search.png in your drawable folder.

Comment: Thank you but I still have the same issue with drawable that I didn't copy. How would I solve it? I'll copy the problem in a sec. I tried solving in the same way by making a drawable value but the following issue arose: Error:Error: In DataSet 'main', no data file for changedFile 'C:\Users\Andy\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\main_activity_actions.xml'. This is an internal error in the incremental builds code; to work around it, try doing a full clean build.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/ic_action_search' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Validates resource references inside Android XML files

Comment: You need to put your icon images inside of your drawable folders before you reference them. You can download android's system icons [here](https://www.google.com/design/icons/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\FunFacts\app\src\main\res\values\dimens.xml: Error: In DataSet 'main', no data file for changedFile. This is an internal error in the incremental builds code; to work around it, try doing a full clean build.

> Scott Junner  on May 12, 2017 If you open the **Build menu** at the top of
>   AndroidStudio, you will see two options there of interest to you.
>   **"Clean Project"** and "Rebuild Project". Try those one after the other
>   and see what results you get. Other than that I don't really know.

It works for me.